# Quickly send commands to nested tmux sessions while preserving functionality of <C-a>

Tags: tmux

Right now I'm using the following mappings for nested tmux sessions:

```
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-t
bind-key -n C-a send-prefix
```

This let's me switch panes in my main tmux session using C-t and switch panes in my nested tmux sessions using C-a. However, the problem with this is that before using the above mappings I used `bind C-a send-prefix` so that `C-a C-a` allowed me to jump to the beginning of the line on the shell. Now, however, if I use this mapping and I'm in my main tmux session, `C-a` behaves like `C-t` (switching two letters) and in my nested tmux sessions `C-a` doesn't do anything. So my question is how , with the 3 mappings listed above, can I make `C-a` jump to the beginning of the line in my main tmux-sessions and make `C-a C-a` jump to the beginning of the line in my nested tmux-sessions?